# Why am I getting "Extra content at the end of the document" in my PHP page?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

This is my error:

> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I just copied the code from [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/tutorials/amazon-web-services-php/).

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
function awsRequest($searchIndex, $keywords, $responseGroup = false, $operation = "ItemSearch", $pageNumber = 1){
    $service_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService";
    $associate_tag = "your-associate-tag";
    $secret_key = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
    $access_key = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY";

    // build initial request uri
    $request = "$service_url&Operation=$operation&AssociateTag=$associate_tag&SearchIndex=$searchIndex&Keywords=".urlencode($keywords)."&ItemPage=$pageNumber";

    // parse request into params
    $uri_elements = parse_url($request);
    $request = $uri_elements['query'];
    parse_str($request, $parameters);

    // add new params
    $parameters['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
    $parameters['Version'] = $version;
    $parameters['AWSAccessKeyId'] = $access_key;
    if($responseGroup){
        $parameters['ResponseGroup'] = $responseGroup;
    }
    ksort($parameters);

    // encode params and values
    foreach($parameters as $parameter => $value){
        $parameter = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($parameter));
        $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
        $request_array[] = $parameter . '=' . $value;
    }
    $new_request = implode('&', $request_array);

    // make it happen
    $signature_string = "GET\n{$uri_elements['host']}\n{$uri_elements['path']}\n{$new_request}";
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $signature_string, $secret_key, true)));

    // return signed request uri
    return "http://{$uri_elements['host']}{$uri_elements['path']}?{$new_request}&Signature={$signature}";
}
// make the request
$xml = simplexml_load_file(awsRequest("VideoGames", "call of duty", "Images", "ItemSearch", "1"));

// now retrieve some data
$totalPages = $xml->Items->TotalPages;
echo "<p>There are $totalPages pages in the XML results.</p>";

// retrieve data in a loop
echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($xml->Items->Item as $item){
    echo "<li>".$item->ASIN."</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

I'm deploying this on AWS.

Comment: This isn't a real question. You're just copy/pasting some stuff. How about explaining what you're trying to do and showing only the relevant code, where the error occurs?

Comment: Get rid of that whitespace before the opening `<?php`. Your initial `header()` call will not work correctly with the whitespace output beforehand! But the error you're looking at is likely to do with invalid XML from the `simplexml_load_file()` call.

Comment: i already remove the whitespace how to fix it?

Comment: You're also not spitting out XML most likely, by adding HTML to the end. So your header will clash with the content. Build the program up a bit at a time and learn what each bit does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your code editor doesn't include a BOM in the document. I know for a fact that notepad++ and some others include this by default. If it is included, it will insert invisible characters into your document, which looks like output to the server, causing the error messages you're seeing. Try copying and pasting your code into a NEW document that does not have the BOM.

Creating a new php document in Dreamweaver (or other editor) WITHOUT the BOM (byte order mark) should solve the issue.